# How do I access protected data from a Request::forge in fuelphp

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, protected, controllers, fuelphp

I'm currently writing unit tests to get full code coverage on an app.  I need to get coverage on the controllers.  To get a request object I use :

```
$controller = Request::forge('mycontroller/view/1')->execute()->response();
```

How do I get access to the information in ["data":protected] so I can make assertions on the test data?

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection to make the properties accessable.